# I don't understand the program

Tags: java

I wanted a program which could list all the contents available in a directory. I found a nice code in java2's.com, 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ListingtheDirectoryContents.htm

And here is the code,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dir {

  static int indentLevel = -1;

  static void listPath(File path) {
    File files[]; 
    indentLevel++; 

    files = path.listFiles();

    Arrays.sort(files);
    for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
      for (int indent = 0; indent < indentLevel; indent++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
      }
      System.out.println(files[i].toString());
      if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
        listPath(files[i]);
      }
    }
    indentLevel--; 
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    listPath(new File(".\\code"));
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is the variable `n` in the first `for` loop. If it is not defined anywhere, then why is the program not showing any error?

Comment: This is actually a bad example. It's not threadsafe. I'd refactor `indentLevel` as local variable and pass it around as another argument.

Comment: @BalusC: agreed, it's an awful piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 int i, n;
```

would declare two ints.

In the code

```
  int i = 0, n = files.length;
```

declares and initialises them.

Comment: +1  Those pesky semicolons are easy to forget when you see a comma in Java for loops.

Comment: It's a beautiful piece of obfuscated code. (brr, don't do everything that is allowed by the JLS). Nice explanation, +1!

Answer (score 4):

It's declared right there, as an `int`. The comma separates the multiple variable declarations.

Comment: It also could easily be removed in favour of just `i < files.length`.  This way is less readable in what I can only assume to be a misguided attempt at optimization.  Better yet, just use `for ( File file : files ) {...`

Answer (score 0):

n is defined in the for loop in the same way as i.

> int x,y;
>   Would define two variables x and y both as ints. the comma in the for with assignments just looks more complex.